# Area of intersection using integration

Tags: integration, geometry

[image]

Suppose, for the sake of illustration, that $AF=2$, where $F\mathbb{'s}$ coordinates are $(2,0)$ and $A$ is the point of origin; $E=(0,1)$ and circle $A$ has $R=1.5$

How do I solve the area of the intersection of the circle and rectangle **by integration**?

If we let $f(x)=1$, then the area of the rectangle is defined by:
$$\int_0^Ff(x)dx$$

If we let $g(x)=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$, then the area of the circle is defined by:
$$4\int_0^Rg(x)dx$$
Now my best attempt to find the area is through:
$$\int_0^Rg(x)dx-\int_0^{\sqrt{R^2-1}}(g(x)-1)dx$$

The first integral gives me a quarter of the area circle $R$, the second gives me the area of the circle that is outside the rectangle, because the circle and the top line intersects at $x=\sqrt{R^2-1}$

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Consider $x=f(y)$ instead of $y=f(x)$. 
Then the area of intersection is just

\begin{align} 
\int_0^1 \sqrt{R^2-y^2}\,dy
&=\left.\left(
\tfrac12\,y\sqrt{R^2-y^2}
+\tfrac12\,R^2\arctan\frac{y}{\sqrt{R^2-y^2}}
\right)\right|_0^1
\\
&=
\left(
\tfrac12\,\sqrt{R^2-1}
+\tfrac12\,R^2\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{R^2-1}}
\right)
\\
&=
\left(
\tfrac12\,\sqrt{\tfrac{9}{4}-1}
+\tfrac12\,\tfrac{9}{4}\arctan\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tfrac{9}{4}-1}}
\right)
\\
&=\tfrac{\sqrt5}4+\tfrac98\,\arctan(\tfrac{2\sqrt5}5)
\approx 1.38
.
\end{align}

Comment: why should the boundaries be $1$ and $0$? Shouldn't it be $1$ and $R=1.5$?

Comment: @JohnGlenn: Here we are using 
$\int_{y_0}^{y_1} x(y)dy$,
and from this point of view 
the area is bounded between 
the lines $y=y_0=0$ and $y=y_1=1$
and a circular arc. 
In this case it is simpler, 
because as you've noticed,
the usual 
$\int_{x_0}^{x_1} y(x)dx$
includes extra region, that has to be subtracted,
so we need to find the coordinates of the point $H$.

Answer (score 2):

The area of the rectangle is defined by $A_r=w*h\implies A_r=2*1\implies A_r=2$.  However, that is immaterial, as all you want is the area of the circle bounded by $y=0$, $y=1$, $x=0$ and $y^2=(1.5)^2-x^2$.  Solve the circle equation for $x$ and take the definite integrate for $y$ between $0$ and $1$.

NOTE: the circle is not of radius $1$, so you will not get a quarter circle.  You could rescale everything (multiply by $\frac{2}{3}$ so $1.5$ becomes $1$ and the $y=0$ and $y=1$ become $y=0$ and $y=\frac{2}{3}$); then integrate and multiply the resultant area by $(\frac{3}{2})^2$ to put the area back to scale.

Comment: Then I'd just get a quarter of the area of the circle. There is still space in the quarter circle that is not inside the rectangle